# show that for any closed curve $\gamma$ containing $z_0$, $\int _\gamma f=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Let $f(z)$ be holomorphic on a simple connected region A, except possibly not holomorphic at $z_0\in A$. Suppose, however, that  f is bounded in absolute value near $z_0$. show that for any closed curve $\gamma$ containing $z_0$, $$\int _\gamma f=0$$

please any one help me with this problem i did't have any idea for how to solve this problem please help me

Comment: $f$ will have a removable singularity at $z_0$.

Comment: Perhaps Morera's theorem would be al alternative approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following theorem:

If $f:D \to A$ is holomorphic function, except for $z_{0} \in D$ and f is bounded near $z_{0}$, then f can be extended to holomorphic function for all $z \in D$.

It is known as Riemman's Removable Singularity Theorem.

Comment: @7667...so the answer is 0 beacuse by cauchy theorem

Comment: The answer is that$ \int_\gamma f(z)dz = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|z-z_0| = \epsilon} f(z)dz = 0$ using the Cauchy integral theorem, or if you prefer the Green theorem (assuming $f$ is regularized such that $f'$ is continuous). This is one of the steps in proving the Cauchy integral formula and hence Riemann's theorem on removable singularities. @nareshnayer